# Need my program to crash if audio file is missing

Tags: java

Pretty straightforward question. My program uses some wav files, and I'd like for it to crash if any of the files is missing. Here's the particular section of my code:

```
AudioClip clickSound;
{
    try {
        clickSound = Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file:click.wav"));
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException mUrlE) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This catches MalformedURLExceptions, but it will still run if the file is missing. How can I detect if the file is missing, so that I can System.exit()?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to let that exception go unhandled so your program will give an error message instead of exiting cleanly?

Comment: Why not calmly print an error message instead of dropping out of operation so abruptly?

Comment: @kviiri Yes that makes sense, I'll change that in my code thanks

Comment: Just catch the exception you get when the file is missing?

Comment: @Ingo Thing is that it doesn't throw an exception if the file is missing, only if the Url is malformed, which it is not.

Comment: What does it do then, @user3026127? Perhaps the clickSound is null then, so check this.

Comment: @Ingo, `newAudioClip` simply calls a constructor of `AppletAudioClip`,  which swallows all IO exceptions - this seems ugly, but is true. Sources [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/applet/AppletAudioClip.java#AppletAudioClip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just check if the file exists
before you try to load wav data from it.

```
File f = new File(strFilePath);
if(f.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
    /* crash the way you like */
}
```